# What is the mechanism behind Microsoft’s enforcement of server bans in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

There is tomfoolery amok, and Microsoft is trying to cause more controversy by banning servers for various things they suddenly don't like. Here's one [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZj06sd-Wmg) explaining it:

How does Microsoft ban a *Minecraft* server, though? I play on Java and run a small private server, and aside from the client and server authenticating a player, I didn't think there was a Microsoft server in the mix at all. I've debated even turning that off, but I haven't yet. Is this a *Bedrock* thing where Microsoft serves as a proxy/portal for users to access servers?

When I searched the internet at large, all I could find were references to Microsoft banning ***players***, not ***servers***.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are not Microsoft and we don't know the reasons why a server can be banned

Comment: I'll leave it up to the community to decide what to do with this question, but I do feel it's somewhat geared towards a "developer intent" style answer which wouldn't be on topic for this site (but maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, which would only make it unclear instead).  It's difficult for us to know what Microsoft does to determine if a server will be banned or not, or how they do it. That information probably is guarded because if it was publicly available, it could make dodging a ban easier. Regardless, please refrain from using comments in the previous manner.

Comment: While it may seem that only the server and client is involved, when connecting to a server does requires connecting to Minecraft's authentication server, which is owned by Microsoft, to verify that the player is actually an user that legitimately has an access to the game(in other words, to prevent pirate user from connecting to a server). I do not know why Microsoft bans a server, though.

Comment: @Samstercraft 5 people are needed to close a question, and if it was wrongly closed then 5 people can reopen it. It's not stupid nor toxic. It's just how the community works. This question was a borderline case, imho.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to connect to a banned Java Edition server, you will get the error message "Unknown Host."
There is an automated Twitter Account that lists these banned servers:   [BlockedServers](https://twitter.com/BlockedServers)

The servers are stored as hashes, so the server names might be unknown.
Also, they ban all the subdomains of a domain name so they can't just change the beginning (for example changing play.X.com to mc.X.com to avoid the ban).

Comment: so this is a DNS block basically?